# ¿Cómo implementar la interfaz Comparable?

Tags: java

Tengo que realizar una jerarquia de clases en la que tengo

1 - Producto

1.1 - Libro tiene LibroDigital - LibroFisico

1.2 - Ropa tiene Pantalon - Camisa

Se me pide que implemente las interface `Comparable` para comparar libros por su isbn (atributo de la clase LIBRO), mi duda es... ¿Donde se implementa la interfaz y donde se implementa el metodo compareTo? ¿En la clase Libro o en las Hijas LibroDigital y LibroFisico?

Es decir hacer esto:

```
public abstract class Libro extends Producto implements Comparable
```

Lo que provoca que tenga que implementar el metodo compareTo en las Hijas. Que va a tener el mismo código en ambas.

¿Puedo hacer que solo Libro tenga el metodo compareTo? ¿Que parametro debe recibir el metodo?

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
public int compareTo(Libro o)

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    this.isbn.compareTo(((Libro) o).getisbn)
}
```

En la API se habla de Object aunque supongo que como ejemplo y se permite cambiar por cualquier objeto con el que estes trabajando... O se debe pasar Object y hacer el cast correspondiente.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Puedo hacer que solo Libro tenga el metodo compareTo? ¿Que parametro debe recibir el metodo?

Si, y lo estas haciendo bien. Pero en lugar de implementar `Comparable` implementa `Comparable<Libro>`:

```
public abstract class Libro
    extends Producto
    implements Comparable<Libro>
```

Y asi te ahorras el cast en:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Libro o) {
    this.isbn.compareTo(o.isbn);
}
```